# CSS: inline style gets applied to <fieldset> but when I write the same code to external css and reference by id no style applied

Tags: html, css, forms, fieldset

https://jsfiddle.net/tdyd5naw/

The css file is linked correctly as the header and footer divs do get styled. I am thinking it is a problem with the selectors but after trying as many options that seemed relevant from W3C I am at a loss.

Here is the relevant html

```
<body>

   <div class = "header"><h1>Library</h1>
   </div>

   <form action = "newUser.php" method = "POST">


      <fieldset  id="newAc">
         <legend>New Accouunt Details</legend>
         Choose Username: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "uname"/><br>
         Choose Password: <br>
         <input type = "password" name = "pass1"/><br>
         Re-Enter Password: <br>
         <input type = "password" name = "pass2"/><br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id = "personalInfo">
         <legend>Personal Info</legend>
         First Name: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "fname"/><br>
         Surname: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "sname"/><br>
         Address Line 1: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "addr1"/><br>
         Address Line 2: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "addr2"/><br>
         City: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "city"/><br>
         Telephone Home: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "hphone"/><br>
         Telephone Mobile: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "mphone"/><br>
      </fieldset>

      <input type = "submit" value = "Register"/><br>

   </form>

   <div class = "footer">
   </div>

</body>
```

and here is the corresponding CSS

```
#newAc {
   position:relative; 
   disblay:block; 
   float:left; 
   top: 100px; 
}

#personalInfo{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   top: 100px
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tdyd5naw/

Comment: Add it to question so others can see it too.

Comment: No no. Your CSS isn't on JSfiddle. you need to upload it directly in the CSS box. Referencing to it won't work unless it's local.

Comment: what you mean upload the file style.css? I have pasted the css in and it works?

Comment: You are 100% right. I assumed you didn't upload it because I saw <...style.css...> in your html, and thought that you did that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing it wrong.change it from feildset #newAc  to feildset#newAc or #newAc
The difference is 
 1. feildset #newAc is you are looking for an element with #newAc in a 
    feildset
 2. feildset#newAc is looking for an element within feildset
    with id #newAc
 3. #newAc is looking for an element which has id #newAc

```css
#newAc {
   position:relative; 
   disblay:block; 
   float:left; 
   top: 100px; 
}

#personalInfo{
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   top: 100px
}
```

```html
 <fieldset  id="newAc">
         <legend>New Accouunt Details</legend>
         Choose Username: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "uname"/><br>
         Choose Password: <br>
         <input type = "password" name = "pass1"/><br>
         Re-Enter Password: <br>
         <input type = "password" name = "pass2"/><br>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset id = "personalInfo">
         <legend>Personal Info</legend>
         First Name: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "fname"/><br>
         Surname: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "sname"/><br>
         Address Line 1: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "addr1"/><br>
         Address Line 2: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "addr2"/><br>
         City: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "city"/><br>
         Telephone Home: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "hphone"/><br>
         Telephone Mobile: <br>
         <input type = "text" name = "mphone"/><br>
      </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you.  fieldset#newAc {...} Thats working now. Not with just #newAc though. I guess the id is nested too deep to be selected alone?

Comment: it works on jsfiddle but still not in chrome on my localhost server...any ideas?

Comment: is your css in an external file...if so,did you add the reference to that file in your html page

Comment: Geeky yes I did. The css is styling the header and footer divs. As per instructions from jsfiddle I have deleted the html and head tags. I have the header and footer syled with fixed position. I commented both of them out in the css file and html file to see if that did anything. To my shock both header and footer remained and form unchanged. I have ensured all files are saved and running from the correct location. What could cause this?

Comment: The html code is saved in a .php file if that makes any difference?

Comment: Going to create new question as problem has changed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40518915/incorrect-output-when-file-called-from-xampp-folder-in-chrome

Comment: I could not understand correctly,but in jsfiddle you need not write html ,head and all the tags but in your local version you need to have html,head ,within head you need to provide the reference to css file..if this is not the case your html page would behave weirdly